# Python Beginner: How do I print the name of a variable instead of the int that is connected to the variable?

Tags: python

Beginner in python here.
For an assignment I need to get input from the user for whole hours worked on weekdays.
After I get this, I need to print a summary and based on the hours that the user inputs, messages show up saying they worked too much or not enough on a given day.
However. I understand that because I have given the variable a weekday name, the integer I get is a number.
So when I link this it prints just the numbers and not the weekday name.

How can I improve the code so the message would print Too many hours worked on Monday instead of Too many hours worked on 9.

However. I understand that because I have given the variable a weekday name, the integer I get is a number.
So when I link this it prints just the numbers and not the weekday name.

How can I improve the code so the message would print Too many hours worked on Monday instead of Too many hours worked on 9.
I know in the code I have put the days of the week in a row so it prints Too many hours worked on 9 etc

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
week = input("Enter Current Working Week: ")
id = input("Enter Employee ID: ")
name = input("Enter Employee Name: ")
monday = int(input("Enter hours worked for Monday: "))
tuesday = int(input("Enter hours worked for Tuesday: "))
wednesday = int(input("Enter hours worked for Wednesday: "))
thursday = int(input("Enter hours worked for Thursday: "))
friday = int(input("Enter hours worked for Friday: "))

print("Summary for Employee", id,)
for i in monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday:
    if i > 8:
        print("Too many hours worked on", monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday)
    elif i < 4:
     print("Insufficient hours worked on", monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday))
```

Comment: Use a dictionary where keys are day names and values are the number of hours worked on that day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple Example, you can modify whatever you needed.

```
# Dictionary mapping weekday numbers to names
weekday_names = {
    1: "Monday",
    2: "Tuesday",
    3: "Wednesday",
    4: "Thursday",
    5: "Friday"
}

# Initialize an empty list to store the hours worked for each weekday
hours_worked = []

# Get input from the user for each weekday
for i in range(1, 6):
    hours = int(input(f"Enter the number of hours worked on {weekday_names[i]}: "))
    hours_worked.append(hours)

# Print the summary and check for hours worked
for i in range(5):
    if hours_worked[i] > 8:
        print(f"Too many hours worked on {weekday_names[i+1]}.")
    elif hours_worked[i] < 8:
        print(f"Not enough hours worked on {weekday_names[i+1]}.")
    else:
        print(f"Worked exactly 8 hours on {weekday_names[i+1]}.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes way more sense then what I tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

The calendar module has a convenient means of getting the names of the days of the week. This means that you can simplify your code like this:

```
import calendar

days_worked = {}
hid = 8 # hours in a day

# build a dictionary keyed by day names
for dow in calendar.day_name[:5]:
    days_worked[dow] = float(input(f'Enter the number of hours worked on {dow}: '))
# analyse the dictionary
for k, v in days_worked.items():
    msg = 'Too many' if v > hid else 'Too few' if v < hid else f'Exactly {hid}'
    print(f'{msg} hours worked on {k}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
week = input("Enter Current Working Week: ")
id = input("Enter Employee ID: ")
name = input("Enter Employee Name: ")
# dictionary to store hour worked for each day
hours = {}
# loop to get hours worked for each day
for day in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']:
hours[day] = int(input("Enter hours worked for " + day + ": "))

print("Summary for Employee", id,)
for day in hours:
    if hours[day] > 8:
       print("Too many hours worked on", day)
    elif hours[day] < 4:
        print("Insufficient hours worked on", day)
```

I think this will help you understand it more easily on how to use dictionaries

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you're printing the hours worked directly, instead of printing the day those hours correspond to. You can solve this problem by storing the days and their corresponding hours in a dictionary, and then iterating over that.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
week = input("Enter Current Working Week: ")
id = input("Enter Employee ID: ")
name = input("Enter Employee Name: ")

# Create a dictionary to store days and hours
work_hours = {
    "Monday": int(input("Enter hours worked for Monday: ")),
    "Tuesday": int(input("Enter hours worked for Tuesday: ")),
    "Wednesday": int(input("Enter hours worked for Wednesday: ")),
    "Thursday": int(input("Enter hours worked for Thursday: ")),
    "Friday": int(input("Enter hours worked for Friday: "))
}

print("Summary for Employee", id,)
for day, hours in work_hours.items():
    if hours > 8:
        print("Too many hours worked on", day)
    elif hours < 4:
        print("Insufficient hours worked on", day)
```

Comment: Using input() in a dictionary constructor like that will work but... seriously?